# How to manage the foreign keys insertions in DB?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

I develop a little object parser (for SQL files that allows me to find easily the list of all tables used in a procedure) and I've the following model :

3 tables :

- Object (ID, Name, LastWriteTime)
- Table (ID, Name)
- ObjectTable (ObjectID, TableID)

I've the 3 corresponding classes :

Object - List of files scanned:

```
[Table(Name = "object")]
public class SourceFile : IEquatable<SourceFile>
{
    public SourceFile()
    { }

    [Column(Name = "id", IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public Guid ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column(Name = "lastwritetime")]
    public DateTime LastWriteTimeUtc
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column(Name = "name", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public String Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool Equals(SourceFile other)
    {
        return Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Table - List of all tables in the DB:

```
[Table(Name = "table")]
public class SourceTable : IEquatable<SourceTable>
{
    public SourceTable()
    { }

    [Column(Name = "id", IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public Guid ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column(Name = "name", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public String Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool Equals(SourceTable other)
    {
        return Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

ObjectTable - For each object, the list of table used :

```
[Table(Name = "object_table")]
public class SourceFileTable
{
    [Column(Name = "object_id", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public Guid ObjectID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [Column(Name = "table_id", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public Guid TableID
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the ID of object & table are DBGenerated, so my question is, how can I add values in ObjectTable using the generated IDs? There only given once inserted in DB, not before.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the entity objects that you have created, Linq-to-sql will figure it out for you. As long as your foreign keys are ok in the DB something like this will work:

```
using (db = new datacontext())
{ 
    var parent = new parent();
    var child = new child();
    parent.children.ad(child);
    db.parents.insertonsubmit(parent);
    db.submitchanges();
 }
```

So you do not add the keys but the objects. The same will work for an association like yours.

**Update**
In your case it will look like (by heart, so please check for typo's)

```
using (db = new datacontext())
{
var o = new Object();
var t = new Table();
db.objects.insertonsubmit(o);
db.tables.insertonsubmit(t);
var objecttable = new objecttable();
objecttable.object = o;
objeecttable.tbale = t;
db.objecttables.insertonsubmit(objecttable);
db.submitchanges();
```

}

Or is your question about how to define the foreign keys in the database? That is done with a statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE ORDERS 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (customer_sid) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(SID);
```

Comment: Looks good, but how can I say that `children` in `parent` object refers to table `ObjectTable` ?